# Spotify API Authorization Code Flow failing ({'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Invalid authorization code'})

Tags: python, authentication, request, spotify

So, I'm trying to build a Spotify API Authorization Code Flow from scratch and I have the following code:

```
class SpotifyAPIFlow(object):
    access_token = None
    access_token_expires = datetime.datetime.now()
    access_token_did_expire = True
    client_id = None
    client_secret = None
    token_url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    auth_url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"

    def __init__(self, client_id, client_secret, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client_secret = client_secret

    def get_client_credentials(self):
        """
        :return: a base 64 encoded string
        """
        client_id = self.client_id
        client_secret = self.client_secret
        if client_secret is None or client_id is None:
            raise Exception("You must set client id and client secret!\n")
        client_creds = f"{client_id}:{client_secret}"
        client_creds_b64 = base64.b64encode(client_creds.encode())
        return client_creds_b64.decode()

    def get_token_headers(self):
        client_creds_b64 = self.get_client_credentials()
        return {"Authorization": f"Basic {client_creds_b64}"}

    def get_token_data(self):
        return {"grant_type": "authorization_code"}

   def perform_authentication(self):
        auth_url = self.auth_url
        headers = {'client_id': self.client_id, 'response_type': 'code',
                   'redirect_uri': 'https://open.spotify.com/collection/playlists', 'scope': 'user-top-read'}
        auth_code = requests.get(auth_url, headers)
        print(auth_code.headers['set-cookie'])


        token_headers = self.get_token_headers()

        payload = {
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'code': auth_code,
            'redirect_uri': 'https://open.spotify.com/collection/playlists',
        }
        #
        access_token_request = requests.post(url=self.token_url, data=payload, headers=token_headers)
        access_token_response_data = access_token_request.json()
        print(access_token_response_data)
        # access_token = access_token_response_data['access_token']
```

To the first request in the perform_authentication function, I get a response with the status 200, which as far as I'm aware means it's all good, but what I found to be real sketchy is that after requesting it didn't redirect me at all to any site, for whatever reason, and they didn't even make me accept the scopes (I'm using pycharm) and I know the auth code should be something related to the url it redirects me to, but it doesn't redirect me to anything
As I still quite am a starter at this stuff, I'd appreciate any help as to why it doesn't work as I want it to, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with the same issue as well and after experimenting, though the documentation says to input the grant_type as `authorization_code`, it will work if you use `client_credentials` in the payload definition.

Edit: I misunderstood the data flow, we should be using the Client Credentials Flow.

Spotify's Client Credentials Flow Documentation: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/

```
payload = {
    'grant_type':"client_credentials",
    'code': auth_code,
    'redirect_uri':'https://open.spotify.com'
    }
```